# Replace a string/line in PDF as per co-ordinate placeholders and re-align content of PDF using java

Tags: java, pdf

I need to replace a string/line in PDF as per co-ordinate placeholders and re-align content of PDF.

I am able to find a text as per co-ordinate and successfully replace as well. But suppose if new text/string is longer than existing string then pdf is not re-align existing text and line like MS word document.

========================================================================

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String inFile = "format1.pdf";
    String outFile = "formatCov.pdf";
    String oldValue = "DRAFT";
    String newValue = "Final test";
    PDDocument document = null;
    try {
        document = PDDocument.load(new File(inFile));
        if (document.isEncrypted()) {
            System.err.println("Error: Encrypted documents are not supported for this example.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println(oldValue + " => " + newValue);

        document = _ReplaceText(document, oldValue, newValue);
        document.save(outFile);
    } finally {
        if (document != null) {
            document.close();
        }
    }
}

private static PDDocument _ReplaceText(PDDocument document, String searchString, String replacement)
        throws IOException {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(searchString) || StringUtils.isEmpty(replacement)) {
        return document;
    }

    for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
        PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
        parser.parse();
        List tokens = parser.getTokens();

        for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++) {
            Object next = tokens.get(j);
            //System.out.println("next =" + next.toString());

            if (next instanceof Operator) {
                Operator op = (Operator) next;
                System.out.println("operator = " + op.getName());   
                String pstring = "";
                int prej = 0;

                // Tj and TJ are the two operators that display strings in a PDF
                if (op.getName().equals("Tj")) {
                    // Tj takes one operator and that is the string to display so lets update that
                    // operator
                    COSString previous = (COSString) tokens.get(j - 1);
                    String string = previous.getString();
                    System.out.println(string);
                    string = string.replaceFirst(searchString, replacement);
                    previous.setValue(string.getBytes());
                } else if (op.getName().equals("TJ")) {
                    COSArray previous = (COSArray) tokens.get(j - 1);
                    for (int k = 0; k < previous.size(); k++) {
                        Object arrElement = previous.getObject(k);
                        if (arrElement instanceof COSString) {
                            COSString cosString = (COSString) arrElement;
                            String string = cosString.getString();

                            if (j == prej) {
                                pstring += string;
                            } else {
                                prej = j;
                                pstring = string;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(pstring);
                    //if (searchString.contains(pstring.trim())) {
                    if (pstring.trim().contains(searchString)) {
                        System.out.println(pstring.trim());
                        COSString cosString2 = (COSString) previous.getObject(0);
                        cosString2.setValue(replacement.getBytes());

                        int total = previous.size() - 1;
                        for (int k = total; k > 0; k--) {
                            previous.remove(k);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // now that the tokens are updated we will replace the page content stream.
        PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(document);
        OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
        ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
        tokenWriter.writeTokens(tokens);
        out.close();
        page.setContents(updatedStream);
    }

    return document;
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Can you show us an example of what you are looking to achieve?

Comment: What you call "re-aligning" in general is very complicated. PDF is no word processing format, it is a final format in which everything is at a fixed location. Unless you only need to support a very simple kind of PDFs, you'll have to invest many person years to implement something that at least most of the time does what you want.

Comment: hi mypetlion, as you have asked, please find attached my code. I want to replace new value with old value. But as length of new value is more then old value, it will overlap to other contain of pdf.

Comment: Your manipulation of the **Tj** and **TJ** arguments shows that you appear to have to deal with very specific kinds of PDFs only because that approach fails for perhaps 90% of the PDFs out in the wild. Thus you might help us help you by sharing representative examples.